# What is the right way to iterate through a kdb partitioned table in an client application?

Tags: kdb

I want to process all the rows of a kdb table in an R program (I use qserver.R). One way to do this is to initialize a memory handler and then iterate through all the rows one of the time, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803232/how-to-create-a-cursor-in-kdb):

```
t: select from mytable where ts>12:30:00,ts<15:00:00,price,msg="A"
t[0]
t[1]
t[2]
...
```

I want to limit the number of client/server calls in R to loop as fast as possible.
How can I fetch multiple rows for each call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: my answer below assumes that `mytable` is the partioned database, but that you now have `t` in memory.

another option using `cut` (using "chunks" of 1,000,000 as per your earlier post)

```
  (`int$1e6) cut t
```

now you have a list of table "chunks" of your desired size and you can use accordingly.

I frequently use this for certain functions (particularly in combination with `peach`).

A pattern I've found useful is:

```
 f:`function that does something useful on chunks`
 fa:`function that reaggregates up to final results`
 r:fa raze f peach (`int$`size`)cut t
```

if you're `t` is really large (both vertical/horizontal) you might want to avoid `cut` directly on the table for memory reasons, but can instead `cut` a list of indices for the table into the appropriate size and then feed the indices to your `f` and have that index to the `t` and grab what you want.

Below a quick comparison of both approaches (note that `f` here is pointless, but just to prove the point of the `cut` on `t` versus indices)

```
   q)t:flip (`$"c",/:string til 100)!{(`int$1e7)?100} each til 100
   q)\ts a:raze {select c1,c99 from x}each 1000 cut t
   3827 4108103072j
   q)\ts b:raze {select c1,c99 from t[x]}each 1000 cut til count t
   3057 217623200j
   q)4108103072j%217623200j
   18.87714
   q)a~b
   1b
```

Answer (score 1):

1. From your previous questions I assume this is a 1 person system so what benefit are you getting from kdb? Why not work fully in R and just use flat memory mapped files directly there? Avoiding unneeded complexity and overhead. If all you want to do is stream the data through R in order that should be simple.
2. Rather than "ts>12:30:00,ts<15:00:00" use "ts within (12:30:00;15:00:00)" it's quicker.
3. The larger the size of chunks you process in the more efficient it is likely to be. 100 seems quite small.

Regards,
Ryan Hamilton

Comment: This is one of the many uses we do of the db, and yes the block size in the query is small. I set it to 100 to simplify the question. I've found 1,000,000 rows at the time to be a good step for my system.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted out, this returns 100 rows each time:

```
\l /data/mydb
t: select from mytable where ts>12:30:00,ts<15:00:00,price,msg="A"
select [0 100] from t
select [100 100] from t
select [200 100] from t
..
```